# Trouble replacing 2 single quotes with a decimal in an Excel cell with RTD formula

Tags: excel-2010

I am using RTD to pull option quotes into an excel spreadsheet
The problem I have is the value that is pulled in has a format of 0''14 I already verified with the find button that those are 2 single quotes and not one double quote and I used the "Look in values" option
to find all of them
In the cell next to it I can copy and paste the value with the same format and using the find button it finds that cell as well

The problem is when I use the replace to replace the 2 single quotes with a decimal it works for the copied cell but not on the one that has the formula

In the find/replace window there is an option on the find page to "look" in formulas or values
The one I pasted in shows up in both options but the one with the RTD formula only shows up if I have it set to values
When I click on replace page the value option is no longer listed so if I click on find again it cannot find it because it's not in the formula bar, it's only in the result cell

I tried using the replace function  in vba but that places the value with the decimal in the formula bar so it will no longer update the RTD value

Another thing I tried was using the RIGHT function in the formula bar to use just the right 2 digits and that works as long as the values stay within 0.10 and 0.99

I was wondering if there is another way to find a solution for this problem that I did not think of

I tried to use the find/replace and also tried the replace function in excel and vba

Answer (score 0):

I used the SUBSTITUTE formula and it seems to work better than the REPLACE formula

Just to clarify my answer in order to help others
This is a problem when getting /ZB1M23 (30 Year bond option symbol ) quotes from Think or swim platform into excel It comes in the format like this 0''13 The 13 is not a decimal but it is tick value  Excel cannot deal with '' so I had to convert it to decimal at first so assuming I have 0''13 in A1 using the formula in cell B1 =SUBSTITUTE(A1,"''",".") will give me 0.13
After that I can do the calculation by multiplying the decimal value in B1 by the tick value to get the correct dollar value value of the option

Those are 2 single quotes in between the double quotes in case it's hard to see

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).